# Association only unique with attribute

Tags: interlis

I'm doing a migration of an old data model. The relation between the `ADRESSE` and the `ORGANISATION` is a m:n relation with a table `ORG_ADRESSE`. There are some entries with the same references pairing but different `ADRESSTYP_ID`. The ilivalidator reports the following error.

OID ...xxx:yyy of object `ORG_ADRESSE` already exists in `ASSOCIATION`

The definition looks like that:

```
   ASSOCIATION ORG_ADRESSE =
      ADRESSEREF -- {0..*} ADRESSE;
      ORGANISATIONREF -- {0..*} ORGANISATION;
      id                            :           INTEGER8;
      ORGANISATION_ID               :           INTEGER8;
      ADRESSE_ID                    :           INTEGER8;
      ADRESSTYP_ID                  :           INTEGER8;
    END ORG_ADRESSE;
```

What is missing to involve the attribute `ADRESSTYP_ID` in the uniqueness check?

Answer (score 0):

The uniqueness check is implicit (because its an ASSOCIATION); you can not modify it.

Comment: I was just wondering if it's possible to find a solution by using a view. See Interlis Ref Handbook, Page 70.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue last year: https://github.com/claeis/ilivalidator/issues/262

As far as I understand the INTERLIS-Referenzhandbuch (page 34/35) you have to use CARDINALITY larger than one in the association:

> Zwischen diesen Objekten ist dann nur
> eine solche Beziehungsinstanz zulässig. Mehrere Beziehungsinstanzen zwischen derselben Objektkombination sind nur zulässig, wenn für die Beziehung explizit eine Kardinalität mit Obergrenze grösser eins
> verlangt wird (CARDINALITY). In diesem Fall muss auch eine Objektidentifikation (mittels Property OID)
> verlangt werden.
>
> Between these objects then only such a relationship instance is
> permissible. Multiple relationship instances between the same object
> combination are only permitted if a cardinality with upper limit
> greater than one is explicitly required for the relationship
> (CARDINALITY). In this case, an object identification (by means of
> Property OID) must also be required.

Model:

```
INTERLIS 2.3;

MODEL AssocDummyModel (de)
AT "https://agi.so.ch"
VERSION "2021-11-05"  =

  TOPIC MyTopic =
    OID AS INTERLIS.UUIDOID;

    CLASS Adresse =
      AttrA : TEXT;
    END Adresse;

    CLASS Organisation =
      AttrO : TEXT;
    END Organisation;

    ASSOCIATION Org_Adresse =
      OID AS INTERLIS.UUIDOID;
      AdresseRef -- {0..*} Adresse;
      OrganisationRef -- {0..*} Organisation;
      AttrAssoz : TEXT;
      CARDINALITY = {*};
    END Org_Adresse;

  END MyTopic;

END AssocDummyModel.
```

XTF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TRANSFER xmlns="http://www.interlis.ch/INTERLIS2.3">
  <HEADERSECTION SENDER="ili2gpkg-4.6.0-97c759c6e1adf63b03653871932368050d4ca803" VERSION="2.3">
    <MODELS>
      <MODEL NAME="AssocDummyModel" VERSION="2021-11-05" URI="https://agi.so.ch"/>
    </MODELS>
  </HEADERSECTION>
  <DATASECTION>
    <AssocDummyModel.MyTopic BID="AssocDummyModel.MyTopic">
      <AssocDummyModel.MyTopic.Adresse TID="1542A3E8-1694-4410-BE80-92F7C912AB64">
        <AttrA>Ich bin eine Adresse</AttrA>
      </AssocDummyModel.MyTopic.Adresse>
      <AssocDummyModel.MyTopic.Organisation TID="113BAF61-BA96-4A64-AA8B-21476E5B71B8">
        <AttrO>Ich bin eine Organisation</AttrO>
      </AssocDummyModel.MyTopic.Organisation>
      <AssocDummyModel.MyTopic.Org_Adresse TID="08050F3F-D483-419B-BE2A-62EBE9910506">
        <AdresseRef REF="1542A3E8-1694-4410-BE80-92F7C912AB64"/>
        <OrganisationRef REF="113BAF61-BA96-4A64-AA8B-21476E5B71B8"/>
        <AttrAssoz>Foo</AttrAssoz>
      </AssocDummyModel.MyTopic.Org_Adresse>
      <AssocDummyModel.MyTopic.Org_Adresse TID="8A998959-6FEE-4EB9-B644-D0C81F40A7A5">
        <AdresseRef REF="1542A3E8-1694-4410-BE80-92F7C912AB64"/>
        <OrganisationRef REF="113BAF61-BA96-4A64-AA8B-21476E5B71B8"/>
        <AttrAssoz>Bar</AttrAssoz>
      </AssocDummyModel.MyTopic.Org_Adresse>
    </AssocDummyModel.MyTopic>
  </DATASECTION>
</TRANSFER>
```

This validates with ilivalidator-1.11.11. But: there seems to be a bug in ili2gpkg (ili2db?). The TID of the association will not be exported (https://github.com/claeis/ili2db/issues/431).

And if you really need/want the UNIQUE constraint (and not only be capable of connecting two objects more then once), you can use a UNIQUE constraint in the association `UNIQUE AttrAssoz, AdresseRef, OrganisationRef;`

Answer (score 0):

I was just wondering if there is a way to do that by a view.
See Interlis Ref page 70.

```
DOMAIN
 CHSurface = ... ;
FUNCTION Intersect (Surface1: CHSurface;
 Surface2: CHSurface): BOOLEAN;
CLASS A =
 a1: CHSurface;
END A;
CLASS B =
 b1: CHSurface;
END B;
VIEW ABIntersection
 JOIN OF A,B;
 WHERE Intersect (A.a1,B.b1);
 =
END ABIntersection;
ASSOCIATION IntersectedAB
 DERIVED FROM ABIntersection =
 ARole –- A := ABIntersection -> A;
 BRole –- B := ABIntersection -> B;
END IntersectedAB;
```